# Reading URLs from a file in python?

Tags: python, file, url

Hey guys so I am trying to read URLs from a file and print if the URLs exist/are reachable or not?? I am not sure why this code is not working: 
(I am reading the urls from a .txt file)

the error I am getting is:

```
   name 'in_file' is not defined
```

code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def is_reachable(url):
   if urlopen(url): 
      return True
   else: 
      return False

in_file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
try:
   in_file = open(in_file_name, "r")
except:
   print("Cannot open " + in_file)

line = in_file.readline().replace(" ", "")
print(line)

counter = 0
while line != "":
  if is_reachable(line) == True:
    counter += 1
    print("The URL on line ", counter, "is unreachable!")
    line = in_file.readline()
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: NameError: name 'in_file' is not defined

Comment: `line = in_file.readline()` in the loop is only called if `is_reachable` returns `True`, because of the indentation, too. Why not use a `with open() as in_file: for line in infile:` block?

Comment: @Kris, Post your Traceback error message into your question, this is important clue.

Comment: This is probably because you are getting the exception, and the in_file variable never gets declared/initialized. Can you copy your exact output? If this is the case, you should not try and print a line from the file if it failed to open.

Comment: @AndyW The code works fine up to the point   print(line), it does print the first line from the file

Comment: @SimonFraser Sorry but I am not really good with coding! basically I haven't learned what you said

Comment: Starting simple :)  If you have `in_file` as an open file, you can do `for line in in_file:` and each time through the `for` loop, `line` will be the next line in the file

Comment: I see! So you suggest to use 'for' instead of 'while' loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an else before printing unreachable. or a not checked to print unreachable urls.
Right now even though the url is reachable you are printing its unreachable.

```
counter = 0
while line != "":
    counter += 1
    if not is_reachable(line):
        print("The URL on line ", counter, "is unreachable!")
    line = in_file.readline()
```

there are other issues with your program:
1. If the file is not readable still your program continues
2. you are using a counter variable and explicitly maintaining it. You can easily use enumerate

A better approach would be:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys

def is_reachable(url):
    try: 
        urlopen(url)
        return True
    except: 
        return False

in_file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
lines = []
try:
    with open(in_file_name, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
except:
    print("Cannot open " + in_file_name)
    sys.exit(1)

for counter, line in enumerate(lines):
    if is_reachable(line):
        print("The URL on line ", counter, "is reachable!")
    else:
        print("The URL on line ", counter, "is unreachable!")
```

Comment: Since they're using `counter` to show the line number, they'll need to increment that in all cases. Perhaps `if is_reachable(line) is not True:` then print the error, and increment counter when reading the next line?

Comment: @VikashSingh I tried your code but I am not sure why it cannot open the file

Comment: @Kris try the latest code. I have made a bug fix in cases of failure to open urls.

Comment: @VikashSingh a small error on your code: remove the 'not' when using if !

Answer (score 0):

You should exit the script if you can't open the file. As your code is currently written, you print an exception if the file can't be opened, then try to run the rest of the code anyway.

One quick fix:

```
in_file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
try:
  in_file = open(in_file_name, "r")
except:
   print("Cannot open " + in_file)
   sys.exit(1) ### you will need to import the sys module
```

Also, your output is wrong. You're saying it's UNREACHABLE if urlopen returns True, when you should be printing that it's REACHABLE.

Finally, in is_reachable, you need to handle a likely exception if there is a resolution problem with the URL you're trying to open:

```
def is_reachable(url):
    try: 
      urlopen(url): 
      return True
    except urllib.error.URLError: 
      return False
```

Comment: It was False but I was experimenting around, thank you for telling me. I will try it out

Comment: Makes sense.  I actually think the biggest problem you're likely to encounter is the last one, which is that you need a try/except around your call to urlopen, since that function will raise an exception, not just return False, if the URL is unreachable for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your code:

```
except:
    print('yadaya ' + in_file_name) # you have used in_file
```

I have not test this but is should work:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen # urllib is deprecated

if urlopen('http://google.com').getcode() >= 200 and urlopen('http://google.com') < 400:
    print ('Yes the URL exists and works.')
```

You will have to work extra for following redirection.